# What do i need underscore templates for?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I come from a very strict OOP flash background, and I'm really trying to get deeper into backbone, my question is this:

If I have classes for all views (much like in flash), are there any uses/benefits of the _.template functionality for me, or can i just overlook it for now?

Comment: Well, I take it you've read the docs... if you can do what you want without feeling like you're hacking away I'd say you can leave it as is for now. Just don't forget about it all together

Comment: Yeah I'm quite positive I can get all the functionality of a template in a class and more (which in my mind is better much practice). Just wanted to make sure it wasn't bad practice and I was overlooking anything major. Thanks

Comment: I fully understand why you'd make your own class. But before doing so, I would advise you to at least use the framework as is, too. When interacting with a custom built class, it's very likely you'll spend a lot of time tweaking your class to interact seamlessly with the standard framework objects... perhaps just extend your class from one of the framework's classes, to avoid the most obvious pitfalls? But that's just what I'd do... having struggled with some libs/frameworks in the past when using my own code, I now tend to stick to the FW as much as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup templating, whether with underscore or any other templating framework, is most definitely useful.

It seems that you see View classes and templates as somewhat of a either-or proposition., but that's not really the case. They solve a different problem altogether; they complement each other, not replace.

A view class (`Backbone.View` in your case) scopes and encapsulates the view-related logic and event handling. This is great practice, and should be used whether or not you decide to use a templating engine.

Templates on the other hand simply transpose your data to the HTML, nothing more or less. This is something your view needs to do, and the way I see it, there are a few ways of achieving this:

- Build HTML by string concatenation

  - `"<div>" + this.model.name + "</div>"`... ugh)
- Fill DOM nodes with jQuery

  - `$(".name").text(this.model.name)` ad absurdum...
- Use some kind of data binding

  - Nice, but Backbone doesn't support this out of the box.
  - Plugins do exist, though ([Backbone.ModelBinding](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding), [Rivets](http://rivetsjs.com/), [Stickit](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit)...)
- Use a templating engine

  - Lighter and simpler than databinding
  - Keeps representation separate from logic

Choice is yours, but I wouldn't go without either a data binding or a templating framework. The templates provided by underscore are powerful, but I prefer semantic, logic-less templates such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Yeah I wrote my own library that uses jQuery to populate views (kind of made ActionScript in Coffeescript haha), which has capabilities for model binding. The objects just listen for events to invalidate itself and fetch new data

Answer (score 1):

If you have JSON object to be outputted as HTML in your views, then you could have some benefice from that.

In my experience if you plan to make an app which is more than basic, and which is also going to grow up, than templating is a good practice that will save some time to you later.

You can get more information at the template doc page http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: Made sure to read it before I asked, wouldn't want to waste your time.

But say i have a List of some sort in JSON, and i want to display all tables in some way. I'd just make a class for the table with arguments for the input and loop through the JSON in my parent and create each table.

Comment: To me, templates seem somewhat detached from the overall workflow in Backbone, like they quite not fit in; and kind of contradict the OOP practice

Comment: I apologize August, I did not read your comment. I update the question. The algorithm you describe for creating fields (in a table?) from a JSON makes sense.